# How to set focus and bring window of ThisWorkbook to front?

Tags: excel, vba

**Purpose**
Check for a numeric xls file on my desktop. If not found bring `Thisworkbook` to front.

**Problem**
If there are already opened workbooks, Thisworkbook remains in background. No error is raised.

**Cause**
Function `Get_Highest_Numeric_Name` although the function itself is working.

**What I tried**
Replacing `ThisWorkbook.Activate` with

```
AppActivate ((ThisWorkbook.Name) & " - Excel")
```

I got this error on AppActivate line

> Invalid procedure call or argument

Strangely the error is not raised if I run that code from the code window.
Any way using AppActivate (ThisWorkbook.Name…) is not reliable, because it requires this option ( File name extension ) is enabled on Windows system.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Len(Get_Highest_Numeric_Name("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls")) = 24 Then    'for Question on Stackoverflow
        MsgBox "File not found", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "File not found"
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub


Function Get_Highest_Numeric_Name(strFold As String, Optional strext As String = "*.*") As String
    Dim arrD, lastName As String, lngNb As Double, El
    'Return all files name in an array
    arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    If UBound(arrD) = -1 Then MsgBox "Nothing could be found in the path you supplied...": Exit Function
    arrD(UBound(arrD)) = "@@##": arrD = Filter(arrD, "@@##", False) 'Remove the last (empty) element
 
    For Each El In arrD   'iterate between the array elements
        If IsNumeric(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
            'Compare the lngNb variable (initially 0) with the numeric value:
            If lngNb < CDbl(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
                'addapt lngNb like the bigger number
                lngNb = CDbl(Split(El, ".")(0)): lastName = El
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Get_Highest_Numeric_Name = strFold & lastName 'Build the necessary path
End Function
```

Comment: Please, try `AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption`. `AppActivate` needs a window caption...

Comment: Anyhow, `ThisWorkbook.Activate` looks useless, in that event, since the workbook will be activated by itself. But only after being completely loaded. I am not sure that I understand the problem you have. I places my above comment without reading all the question, only traying a normal use of `AppActivate`. But when the workbook is not open, I am afraid that the necessary window caption is not exposed, yet. Now, why do you need activating it, since activation only consumes Excel resources, rarely bringing some benefit?

Comment: @FaneDure ,I tried by got the same error `Invalid procedure call or argument`

Comment: Probably... I tried explaining above that the use of activation is useless and it cannot work until the workbook is fully loaded. Anyhow, the workbook will be automatically **activated**. That's why I am not sure I understand what you **REALLY** want accomplishing. I cannot imagine how an opening workbook does not become the active one.

Comment: @FaneDure , as my code ,thisworkbook is not automatically activated !

Comment: Does the workbook in discussion have only the subs you show? I cannot see a reason to not be activated, since it is opening. But I admit that I am maybe missing something. What application/workbook is the active one, after this workbook opens? Your (visible) code does not open any other workbook.

Comment: Please, try answering my questions. I don't want downloading it. I cannot test it without having a similar environment. It will try dealing with a path in your computer, i do  not have time to adapt it for my case.

Comment: @FaneDure , there are not additional codes as on question.and sure,on my real workbook, `if file not found` I will deal with it to enter some data manually, that's way I need it to be focused to fornt.I hope you understand me this time.

Comment: I cannot understand that, sorry. **What application/workbook is the active one, after this workbook opens?**

Comment: @FaneDure ,I mean there is another workbook Xls already opened manually , then After I open the workbook in question, the focus still on the first already opened one.

Comment: What happens if you comment all the code in the `Open` event , except the `MsgBox` line? Does it open as it should? I mean, activated...

Comment: @FaneDure If I comment the line of **If condition** , then the code works perfectly and this workbook is focused and brought to front.

Comment: @FaneDure ,sorry but if it still not clear for you , kindly tell me.

Comment: Not the question itself is not clear. I need to understand the environment. The called function opens a cmd.exe window (by "wscript.shell"), but everything should happen in hidden windows. Even if not hidden, theoretically the focus must go back to the previous active application (Excel) and let it go as it should. To activate the opening workbook. Please, try moving the code from `Open` event in `Workbook_Activate` one. What does it hapen?

Comment: Copy it with 'ThisWorkbook.Activate` and without...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried hopelessly adding to the code an additional function **API** into a separate module ,to produce new message box with timeout. 
Anyhow, using this API fixed the issue **(I do not know why this happened).** 
Note: If I comment the line of `MsgBoxTimeout`, the problem error raising again.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      If Len(Get_Highest_Numeric_Name("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls")) = 24 Then
            Call MsgBoxTimeout(0, "File not found", "File not found", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, 0, 2000)
            Exit Sub
     End If
End Sub
```

'This function exists on a separate  module

```
Public Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
```